# Start nginx on bootup when compiled from source on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, apache2, ubuntu-13.10

On my Ubuntu 13.10 webserver, I installed nginx from source as I read a guide on how to do this in order to run both nginx (for my Rails apps) and Apache2 (for my php apps). I have nginx running as a proxy for apache2 on these php web apps. I installed nginx from source in to /opt/nginx, but I also have the Ubuntu default (using app-get) installed, although it isn't running.

Upon reboot, the Ubuntu default nginx starts up, so I need to manually "service nginx stop", then start the source compiled nginx using /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx.

How can I disable the Ubuntu default nginx from starting on bootup and instead have my source compiled nginx start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to `/etc/init.d/` and modify the path in `nginx`.